# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined, with proengsoft / laravel-jsvalidation

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-validate

I'm using [proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) which converts laravel validation request to jquery validation. But I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'laravelValidation' method.
    at Array.<anonymous> (jsvalidation.js:148)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at $.validator.<anonymous> (jsvalidation.js:146)
    at $.validator.check (jquery.validate.js:798)
    at $.validator.checkForm (jquery.validate.js:475)
    at $.validator.form (jquery.validate.js:462)
    at n.fn.init.valid (jquery.validate.js:127)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (wizard?account=20:1471)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I'm using,

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\MyFormRequest') !!}
```

This is the error line,

```
var isArrayRule = param[4].indexOf('[') !== -1;
```

Full method,

```
$.validator.addMethod("laravelValidation", function (value, element, params) {
            var rules = [],
                arrayRules = [];
            $.each(params, function (i, param) {
                // put Implicit rules in front
                var isArrayRule = param[4].indexOf('[') !== -1;
                if (param[3] || laravelValidation.implicitRules.indexOf(param[0]) !== -1) {
                    isArrayRule ? arrayRules.unshift(param) : rules.unshift(param);
                } else {
                    isArrayRule ? arrayRules.push(param) : rules.push(param);
                }
            });

            // Validate normal rules.
            var localRulesResult = validateLocalRules(this, [value], element, rules);

            // Validate items of the array using array rules.
            var arrayValue = ! Array.isArray(value) ? [value] : value;
            var arrayRulesResult = validateLocalRules(this, arrayValue, element, arrayRules);

            return localRulesResult && arrayRulesResult;
        }, '');
```

This is called validate function,

```
rules: {"child_full_name":{"laravelValidation":[["Required",[],"This field is required",true]]}}
```

I have no clue how this happens. Can anyone give any clue to debug this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts found out **proengsoft / laravel-jsvalidation** package has got updated with composer. Laravel version should match with **laravel-jsvalidation** package version.
available versions and laraval matrix can be found [here](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/wiki/Installation).

in my case I have to add **'~3.0'**

```
"proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "~3.0",
```

instead of told in the doc **'^3.0'**. (My laravel is 5.8 and eventually plugin updated to version 4 and stopped)
Keeping this answer since the plugin was very useful if anyone met with the same error.

(Simply if you found the error what you have to do is change the line in composer.json and run **composer install** command)